# Logging into website programmatically returns HTML of login

Tags: java, html

> I have the following Java program which is supposed to login to my Student website programmatically and return the HTML of the Gradebook. However, when I run it, I am returned with the HTML of the actual login site:

```
public class Scraper {

static String formData = "j_username=[username here]&j_password=[password here]";
static String link = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form";


public static void main (String[] args){

   String display = postData(link,formData);
   System.out.print(display);


}

public static String postData (String url, String data){

    URL link = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    String document = null;

    try {
        link = new URL(url);
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    //setCookie(connection);

    //post data
    String postString = data;
    stringBuffer.append(postString);

    try {
        connection.connect();
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    try {
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    try {
        IOUtils.write(stringBuffer.toString(),dataOutputStream,"UTF-8");
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    //handle redirects
    try {
        if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER){
            String redirectURL = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
            String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            URL redURL = null;

            try {
                redURL = new URL(redirectURL);
            }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

            connection = (HttpURLConnection)redURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        document = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,"UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    return document;
}

public static void setCookie(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection){

}


}
```

> I originally tried sending the initial POST request to the request URL shown in the network tab of inspect element (https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check), however, this returns an error and no HTML data. Any help is appreciated as I this is the first time I am attempting something of this nature.
>
> **Update**: After experimenting with the login process, I noticed that the cookie I obtain contains only something along the lines of "lastvisit=95FD925038EF488AA22719B64FB5C4A3" but is missing the "JSESSION_ID". I am unsure as to whether this is causing the problem or not.
>
> **Update #2** I edited my code to comply with the suggestions offered, however, I still get the HTML of the login page rather than the grade data page. Also, I add print statements to display the cookie I obtained and I noticed that the "JsessionID" cookie is missing and instead I only get the "lastvisited" cookie.

```
public class Scraper {

static String formData = "user&pass";
static String link = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form";


public static void main (String[] args){

   String display = postData(link,formData);
   System.out.print(display);


}

public static String postData (String url, String data){

    URL link = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    String document = null;

    try {
        link = new URL(url);
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    //connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    //setCookie(connection);

    String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); //get cookies for session


    //try {
    //    connection.connect();
    //}catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    //try {
    //    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    //}catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    //try {
    //    IOUtils.write(stringBuffer.toString(),dataOutputStream,"UTF-8");
    //}catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    //handle redirects
    try {

            //post data
            String postString = data;
            stringBuffer.append(postString);

            URL redURL = null;

            try {
                redURL = new URL("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check");
            }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

            connection = (HttpURLConnection)redURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

            //connection.connect();

    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String cookie2 = null;

    try {
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

        try {
            IOUtils.write(stringBuffer.toString(),dataOutputStream,"UTF-8");

            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

            cookie2 = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); //get cookies for session

        }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    URL fLink = null;

    try {
        fLink = new URL("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form" + stringBuffer.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) fLink.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);



        try {

            conn.connect();
            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        document = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,"UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    System.out.println("cookie -- " + cookie);
    System.out.println("cookie2 -- " + cookie2);


    return document;
}
}
```

> The output for my cookie print statements is as follows (for experimental purposes)

```
cookie -- lastvisit=A1753DA7F2454A03B58DF8CBD39C22C4; Expires=Tue,   27-Mar-2018 18:27:55 GMT
cookie2 -- null
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried HTTP Client? Or are you trying to decode what the browser does and then mimic that? What was the error when you hit /j_security_check?

There are some libraries that would probably help out handling standard response codes etc

Comment: @TheNorthWes I am trying to mimic browser interaction. I updated my question with further clarification as to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you have to do is essentially make a GET request to the server without login credentials first (to the page you want to retrieve data from, not the actual login page) -- this will essentially allow you to retrieve and store session cookies. Then you can make a POST request with login credentials AND your cookies to the actual login page. It should redirect you to the page you initially sent your request to (the page you are trying to scrape data from. Use Postman or something similar to ensure you are sending the right data in the right way. Good luck!

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Is this common practice with this specific login mechanism? Because it seems like a counterintuitive approach...

Comment: This is generally how you approach Java servlet authentication. If you try tracking the data flow with Postman it might make a bit more intuitive sense for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The GET URL actually responds with the html being returned. You want specific html and you can use a different endpoint to actually return the html you need

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. The login request has to be a POST request, not a GET request.
2. You need to provide a cookie with the login POST request. Therefore you might want to make a get request to the server first and use the Set-Cookie response value in the subsequent POST.

Comment: I updated my question to provide further clarification as I have already tried the strategies you have outlined

Comment: You need to ensure the cookie is correctly set in the request as JSESSIONID. Alternatively try putting the cookie in the URL query sting with JSESSIONID as the parameter name.

Comment: The thing is it seems as though I am unable to get the jsessionid cookie in the first place and thus am unable to set it at all

Answer (score 0):

This site is using Java Servlet authentication mechanism. When you try to get any page that is password protected the server internally issues a forward that returns the login page content. After you post a valid username/password it forwards you to the requested URL.

Note that this is not a redirect, it is managed internally by the application server and the client does not see what is going on at the server side.

To get this to work you need to issue a GET to the page you are trying to retrieve. The server responds with the login page content and the session id as a cookie. You have to save the session id and send it when you post to the form action.

Since I don't have valid credentials to test I cannot guarantee that this will work. With invalid credentials, the server will issue a number of redirects which will eventually change the session, probably because it is invalidated and recreated.

Please try this with valid credentials and let me know if it works. If there are redirects on successful login maybe it will be necessary to disable automatic redirects and do them programmatically, checking for session id changes. Depending on the application server, it may change the session id for security purposes.

That said, this MAY work when you post valid credentials.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Scraper {

    private static final String USERNAME = "user@test.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "secret";
    private static final String GET_URL  = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form";
    private static final String POST_URL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cookies = doGet(GET_URL);
        doPost(POST_URL, cookies);
    };

    /**
     * Send the initial GET request which will forward to the login page
     * and retrieve cookies sent by the server.
     * Cookies are formatted according to HTTP specification so they can be
     * passed to the next request Cookie header.
     * @param getURL URL to get
     */
    public static String doGet(String getURL) {
        StringBuilder formattedCookies = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = conn.getHeaderFields();
            List<String> cookies = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
            ListIterator<String> it = cookies.listIterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String[] parts = it.next().split("; ");
                formattedCookies.append(parts[0]);
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    formattedCookies.append("; ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nGET OUTPUT");
            printContent(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return formattedCookies.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Post the form parameters and get page content.
     * @param postURL URL to post to
     * @param cookies The cookies to send
     */
    public static void doPost(String postURL, String cookies) {
        try {
            String postData = String.format("j_username=%s&j_password=%s",
                URLEncoder.encode(USERNAME, "UTF-8"), PASSWORD);
            URL url = new URL(postURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(postData);
            out.close();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("\n\nPOST OUTPUT");
            printContent(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }    

    public static void printContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code, however, I am still left with the HTML of the login page as the output.

Comment: @Steve Scraping is always tricky. You need to check each response you get from each request. As I pointed out, without valid credentials it is not possible to figure out what is going on. I suspect that after successful login, the server changes the session id so you will have to disable follow redirects and do it yourself by extracting the Location header and doing a new request. Changing the session id after login is a common security measure.

Comment: @whogado The thing is, if you look at this code I wrote: https://pastebin.com/1ZENayhL, I am able to successfully accomplish this task using JSoup without worrying about changing JSessionID etc. Thus, I am not sure what the problem is given I am using basically the same approach (as far as I can see)

Comment: @Steve I see. JSoup is a specialized framework for HTML processing while HttpURLConnection takes care only of the connection. It takes only a wrong encoding or a missing newline to break the whole conversation with the server. JSoup takes care of all the details therefore it works. Certainly it is possible to use HttpURLConnection to accomplish this task but it takes much more effort. If JSoup works for you it is easier to use it. To figure out exactly what is going wrong it would be necessary to set up a proxy to watch what is being transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve the **Set-Cookie** header from the connection, which if you notice in the headers, has two entries. One with the last visited entry and another with the **JSessionID** entry.

In your cookie retrieval the **JSessionID** entry is getting ignored. Retrieve the entries as a List and set it properly.

```
    List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
    }
```

Edit: Try the below code. It gives me unknown username and password.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Scraper {

static String formData = "j_username=user&j_password=pass";
static String link = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String display = postData(link, formData);
    System.out.print(display);

}

public static String postData(String url, String data) {

    URL link = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    String document = null;

    try {
        link = new URL(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    // connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID=82714DD38C05837934F515C5E0BFD1E3;
    // lastvisit=3626F6FB689948B09CEF3DDA56116B7C");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    // connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    // setCookie(connection);

    // String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); //get
    // cookies for session
    List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

    // try {
    // connection.connect();
    // }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    // try {
    // dataOutputStream = new
    // DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    // }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    // try {
    // IOUtils.write(stringBuffer.toString(),dataOutputStream,"UTF-8");
    // }catch (Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    // handle redirects
    try {

        // post data
        String postString = data;
        stringBuffer.append(postString);

        URL redURL = null;

        try {
            redURL = new URL("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) redURL.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        // connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
        }
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        // connection.connect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String cookie2 = null;

    try {
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    try {
        IOUtils.write(stringBuffer.toString(), dataOutputStream, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

        cookie2 = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); // get cookies
                                                            // for session

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    URL fLink = null;

    try {
        fLink = new URL(
                "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=weeklysummary&studentid=100916&action=form"
                        + stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) fLink.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    // conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
    }
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    try {

        conn.connect();
        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        document = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        System.out.println("cookie -- " + cookie);
    }

    System.out.println("cookie2 -- " + cookie2);

    return document;
}
}
```

Comment: After trying your advice, I am still left with the HTML of the login page.

Comment: I tried your edited code and I am still left with the HTML of the login page.

Comment: Did you try updating the username and password to proper values? I can't bypass the page because I don't have a registered username and password.

Comment: Yes, I used my login credentials

Comment: Ok. For me it gives "Invalid user name or password.  Please try again." which is the message I get when I directly try entering the invalid username and password. Try retrieving the JSESSIONID again from the second request and setting it in the third. Not sure if it will help though.

Comment: I too get that message when I do not add my credentials. However, when I do add my credentials, I do not get the message and am left with just the login page HTML. Also, I tried retrieving the JSESSIONID again but that did not help.

Comment: Try seeing the request and response headers from the browser Dev tools and see if you are missing any headers after the authentication call. I guess at this point this is the best I can do without an actual credential

Comment: I updated my question to include all the relevant headers. As far as I can see it seems as though everything is accounted for which is why I am unsure as to why this isn't working

Comment: Yeah. Try debugging and seeing the headers again. I am pretty sure you are close. Just some minor adjustments I believe. Not much I can do from my side I guess. All the best! Let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: Just wondering, could the order of the cookie matter? I notice online the cookie is shown with JSESSIONID first such as in JSESSIONID=1EEDBBAD0F68F814E56D2BE405401E3F; lastvisit=C71DE7F056734971A6F13D1E23060019, however, in my code it is reversed.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **OkHttp library**

> https://github.com/square/okhttp

**then**

```
 public static String postData(String url, String data){               
       try { 

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
       .connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();






MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
          RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, data);
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url(url)
.post(body)
 .addHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
 .addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36")
 .addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
.addHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8")
 .build();
String body = client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
  return  body;


         }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();  return “An error occurred”; }                                        
    }
```